# Save Data from Database within Intellij Ultimate

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, datagrip

I have already made the connection to my Microsoft SQL server database through the intellij plugin. This means that I can see tables and write queries within intellij.

How can I save the data from the tables into objects? I have already read that through the plugin the jdbc driver is installed.

In the following code, you can see, how I used to save objects before getting intellij ultimate. Is there a way to avoid writing this extra code, since there is already a connection to the database?

```
public class DBController {
private static Statement stmt;
private static String query;
static private Connection con = null;

public void initialiseDB() {
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\Me:1433;database=TestDatabase";

try {

  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
  if (con != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected");
  }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void readPeople() {
query = "select * " + "from " + "TestDatabase.dbo.Test_Table";
try {
  stmt = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("Name");
    String year = rs.getString("YEAR");
    // supposedly there is a Person object
    Person person = new Person(name,year);
    peopleList.add(person);
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data-in-ide.html#Export_data_in_IDE.xml

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are making a connection through your plugin in Intellij. You are connecting through your Java code with the DB. I suggest you looking into the Hibernate or SpringJPA frameworks. They will help you to develop your application a lot in the sense of a modern use of connecting to a database.